# Minimal spanning set of vectors for the row space of A

Tags: linear-algebra

Given 
$$A=
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 2 
\end{array} \right]
$$

I need to find the minimal spanning set of vectors for the row space of $A$.

My solution:

So I used Gaussian elimination on $A$ to get

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right]
$$

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right]
$$

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right]
$$

My question is when you are trying to find the minimal spanning set of vectors for row space of A should I stop when I get it in the form of

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right]
$$

Or carry on to get the final reduced matrix of

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right]
$$

Comment: You may consider using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for better formatting.

Comment: sorry I was unable to use it for the matrices, if someone edits I will now use that format

Comment: How did you go from one before the last matrix to the last one? You can't do that with elementary operations...

Comment: i divided the first row by 2

Comment: or multiplying by a half

Comment: The matrix operations of

1. Interchanging two rows or columns,

2. Adding a multiple of one row or column to another,

3. Multiplying any row or column by a nonzero elemen

Answer (score 1):

Find the span of 
$$
A=
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 2 
\end{array} \right].
$$
How precisely to approach this problem? There are a few ways. We will present an intuitive method, then a systematic method and discuss the different forms of the solution.

---

### 1. Opportunity-based method

Many academic exercises are simple enough to allow solution by inspection. In this case,
$$
 2 \left( \text{row } 1 \right) - \text{row } 2 = \text{row } 3.
$$
The first two rows are fundamental, so the span for the range of the row space is written as
$$
  \mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) = \text{span} \left\{ \,
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \\ 4 
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ 6 
\end{array}
\right]
\, \right\}
\tag{1}
$$

---

### 2. Systematic method

The row reduction process. The following reduces the augmented matrix, but you could could by with only the naked matrix.

**Approach 1**

*Column 1*

$$
% operations
\left[
\begin{array}{rcc}
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% augmented matrix
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|ccc}
 2 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% result
=
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr|rcc}
 \boxed{1} & 2 & 3 & 2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

*Column 2*

$$
% operations
\left[
\begin{array}{crc}
 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% augmented matrix
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr|rcc}
 \boxed{1} & 2 & 3 & 2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% result
=
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr|rrc}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & 1 & -2 & \frac{5}{2} & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The boxed pivots identify the fundamental rows, and produce the same result in $(1)$.

**Approach 2**

*Column 2*

For this matrix, there are two fundamental rows. Any choice of the two will work. Here is a choice where we picks rows $1$ and $3$.

$$
% operations
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1 & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% augmented matrix
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr|rcc}
 \boxed{1} & 2 & 3 & 2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% result
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccr|rrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & 1 & -2 & -\frac{3}{2} & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
In this instance the span is
$$
  \mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) = \text{span} \left\{ \,
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \\ 4 
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 3 \\ 5 \\ 2 
\end{array}
\right]
\, \right\}
$$

Conclusion: your span could be written as any combination of two columns.
$$
  \mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) = 
% 1 & 2
\text{span} \left\{ \,
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \\ 4 
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ 6 
\end{array}
\right]
\, \right\}
=
% 1 & 3
\text{span} \left\{ \,
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \\ 4 
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 3 \\ 5 \\ 2 
\end{array}
\right]
\, \right\}
% 2 & 3
=
\text{span} \left\{ \,
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ 6 
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 3 \\ 5 \\ 2 
\end{array}
\right]
\, \right\}
\tag{2}
$$